# Python re match last underscore in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings that look like this

```
S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png
S25m\S25m_1_16Q_0dB.png
S25m\S25m_2_16Q_2dB.png
```

I want to get the string between slash and the last underscore, and also the string between last underscore and extension, so

Desired:

```
[S25m_16Q, S25m_1_16Q, S25m_2_16Q]
[-2dB, 0dB, 2dB]
```

I was able to get the whole thing between slash and extension by doing

```
foo = "S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png"
match = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.(\w+)', foo)
match.group(1)
```

But I don't know how to make a pattern so I could split it by the last underscore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture the groups you want to get.

```
>>> re.search(r'([-\w]*)_([-\w]+)\.\w+', "S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png").groups()
('S25m_16Q', '-2dB')
>>> re.search(r'([-\w]*)_([-\w]+)\.\w+', "S25m\S25m_1_16Q_0dB.png").groups()
('S25m_1_16Q', '0dB')
>>> re.search(r'([-\w]*)_([-\w]+)\.\w+', "S25m\S25m_2_16Q_2dB.png").groups()
('S25m_2_16Q', '2dB')
```

`*` matches the previous character set greedily (consumes as many as possible); it continues to the last `_` since `\w` includes letters, numbers, and underscore.

---

```
>>> zip(*[m.groups() for m in re.finditer(r'([-\w]*)_([-\w]+)\.\w+', r'''
... S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png 
... S25m\S25m_1_16Q_0dB.png
... S25m\S25m_2_16Q_2dB.png
... ''')])
[('S25m_16Q', 'S25m_1_16Q', 'S25m_2_16Q'), ('-2dB', '0dB', '2dB')]
```

Comment: Thanks! How did the pattern differentiate different underscores? Where is the "last underscore" part?

Comment: I see. Now I can understand this one. I guess I don't know `re` very well in general.

Comment: Also helps to know that the underscore is included by the \w wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution (albeit rather messy):

```
>>> import os
>>> s = "S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png"
>>> first, _, last = s.partition("\\")[2].rpartition('_')
>>> print (first, os.path.splitext(last)[0])
('S25m_16Q', '-2dB')
```

Answer (score -3):

I know it says using `re`, but why not just use `split`?

```py
strings = """S25m\S25m_16Q_-2dB.png
S25m\S25m_1_16Q_0dB.png
S25m\S25m_2_16Q_2dB.png"""

strings = strings.split("\n")

parts = []
for string in strings:
    string = string.split(".png")[0] #Get rid of file extension
    string = string.split("\\")
    splitString = string[1].split("_")
    firstPart = "_".join(splitString[:-1]) # string between slash and last underscore
    parts.append([firstPart, splitString[-1]])


for line in parts:
    print line
```

```bash
['S25m_16Q', '-2dB']
['S25m_1_16Q', '0dB']
['S25m_2_16Q', '2dB']
```

Then just transpose the array,

```
for line in zip(*parts):
    print line
```

```bash
('S25m_16Q', 'S25m_1_16Q', 'S25m_2_16Q')
('-2dB', '0dB', '2dB')
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes while editing a question i accidentally submitted before it was finished guys!